# What is the politically correct way for one to refer to God? In other words, how can one eliminate gendered pronouns entirely from one's God-talk?

Tags: personal-pronouns, gender-neutral, political-correctness

It seems that for one to refer to God as *he* bothers some people --- and I can see from where they are coming as I, too, oppose referring to God in the feminine and masculine because God is neither feminine, masculine, female, or male; God is Divine, so God is sexless and genderless.

Yes, I know that referring to God with *he/him* pronouns is not typically seen as problematic by theists and non-theists alike, and I know that referring to God as *she/her* is seen as tongue-in-cheek, but I want to try and avoid feminine or masculine pronouns for God without having to overuse the noun *God*, as in "*humankind was created in God's image; God loved humankind, and God blessed it, and God watches over it".* That to me sounds **awful**. It hurts my eyes to read and it hurts my ears to hear. Alas, however, these are the kinds of "solutions" with which many a proponent of inclusive and neutral God-talk I have come across has come up.

Any solutions for how I can be politically correct and avoid feminine and masculine pronouns in reference to God altogether?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108295/discussion-on-question-by-english-learner-what-is-the-politically-correct-way-fo).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, though it is ostensibly about what language constructs to use around a particular topic, it is more about highly opinionated sociological concepts than what patterns in English actually exist. Maybe should be on a religious.SE?

Answer (score -1):

The Guardian newspaper prides itself on using inclusive, non-discriminatory language - actor, not actress; humankind not mankind; synthetic not manmade, that sort of thing. You could do worse than follow the advice in their style guide:

https://www.theguardian.com/guardian-observer-style-guide-g

> **God** - but he, him etc rather than He, Him

Anyone who has the "imagination" to believe in an all powerful, benevolent deity, probably isn't going to be too offended by references to "he" and "him".

For information, here's the Guardian's entry for political correctness:

> **political correctness** - a term to be avoided on the grounds that it is, in Polly Toynbee’s words, “an empty rightwing smear designed
>   only to elevate its user”

Answer (score -5):

There is no PC means of referring to God. PC is meant to keep such ideas at a remove. God is intrinsically authoritarian and as such is thought of as the parental He, much to be eschewed. In the history of Genesis it is important to know that He was put in opposition to the feminine Earth god, Gia. Check out your Joseph Campbell *Masks of God - Occidental Mythology*.  Careful vocabulary and a good Osteopath can allow you the back breaking contortions needed to satisfy the PC crowd with *They vs He* transliterations. I would focus on the lesson you wish to transmit and not worry about the sex of the deity in question.

It is the Eastern modality of god that allows the two sides to be seen as one. If the English language had a common article for the neuter, as the Germans have *das*, there might be a better way to express it.

Comment: Could you give a pointer or quote supporting "In the history of Genesis He was put in opposition to the female earth god, Gia"?

Comment: @Elliot Well, I didn't know any of that. First, though, I think I agree with you that though God --- the monotheistic one in your case, as it is "he" who you are speaking about --- is, I agree with you, usually and probably supposed to be gendered as masculine, not feminine, and or epicene, there must be a way in English that one can replace the words he/his, she/her, they/them, and it/it's in reference to the monotheistic deity without being wordy, without over-repeating the word "God" as was done in my post for the purpose of example, etc., no?

Comment: @Conrado yes, I, too would like to see this, as it is most interesting.

Comment: I don't understand where you are getting all this from. There are no Earth deities in Genesis, female or otherwise. Further, the Greek earth deity is usually transliterated as Gaia, and she was not worshipped in Israel or the surrounding areas at the time that much of Genesis was written (let alone conceived), so the notion that Hebrew scribes would have put their Adonai in opposition with a Hellenic Earth deity would be quite strange.

Comment: Glad to stir things up a tad. No claim was made that such deities were in Genesis but in the *history* of Genesis. They are discussed at length in Joseph Campbell's *Occidental Mythology*. There the history of god genders et al is tracked along with transitions from stone age to bronze and iron ages. These preceded Greek and Israeli scribes by some number of weeks. As for spelling I will bow to the power of the spell-checker. I will gladly sift through the first half of Campbell for any other details desired.

Comment: @Elliot Sorry, I just saw that _you did_ mention Campbell, and I just didn't understand that you were pointing out the source. My bad!

Comment: @Conrado, No problem. There is plenty to overlook here. Of all the Campbell *Masks of God* I got more from this than any other. I heartily recommend it. Not sure if an answer ever descended for the question here.